# How to include only true positives and false positives, that is ignore false negative classifications in a confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I have performed a **10 fold cross validation** on my data set using **binary decision trees**. I've got **6 trees** (to detect one of the six basic human emotions from facial data points) trained for each fold. I used these trees to classify my test set in each fold. I was asked to provide ***average cross validation results that includes a single 6x6 confusion matrix including only the true positives and the false positives, that is, ignoring false negative classifications*** and then from this matrix calculate average recall, precision rates and F1-measure (I don't have a problem doing this).

I've tried to "manually" create a confusion matrix not including any false positives, however I always get the exact same confusion matrix returned by the built-in MATLAB confusionmat function.

Can anyone please put me in the right direction?